# Android MediaPlayer WakeLock not Working

Tags: android, media-player, wakelock

I've made a basic radio player, the code that makes it play is below and works perfectly except for the setWakeMode method.  When I turn my phone onto standby, the audio will play well for up to 2 minutes, after which, it begins to stop and start.  Any ideas?

N.B. radioPlayer is an instance of MediaPlayer.

```
public boolean startRadio()
{   
    try
    {
        String url = getString(R.string.radioURL); // Radio url.
        radioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        radioPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        radioPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

        radioPlayer.setWakeMode(this.getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        radioPlayer.start();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        showAlert(getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.radioError));
        radioPlayer.release();
        radioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        return false;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: After reviewing another thread elsewhere, I've discovered that this problem seems to be unique to HTC phones, in fact, my Samsung Galaxy Tab survives even without the wake lock at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Your MediaPlayer stop because Wifi go into sleep mode, so you should try using [WifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) to prevent that.

Comment: Oh wow I totally assumed that the mediaplayer.setwakemode would also keep the wifi going but I forgot that it doesn't need it if it doesn't play a stream - which probably happens a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Android Developers Google + page re-posted[ this

Small tip: if you want to keep the screen on while the user is in your app (for example playing a game or watching a video), the best way to do this is with one of these:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn(boolean)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setScreenOnWhilePlaying(boolean)

Don't use a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html unless you have to, since this requires you requesting the WAKE_LOCK permission (so one more permission shown to the user leaving them less likely to install your app). Also using one of the previous APIs allows the system to manage the wake lock for you, so you can not have bugs where the user leaves your app and the screen is still being kept on.

Comment: Thing is, I'm wanting people listening to the radio with this app to be able to put their phone in standby and walk around with it in their pocket if they so wish, or just generally listen without the screen running down their battery so forcing the screen to stay on isn't really an option.

Have added the WAKE_LOCK permission already.  Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: keepScreenOn is bringing a rocketlauncher to a knife fight if you only want the mediaplayer to keep playing. :)

Answer (score -1):

## set keepScreenOn=true

***The easiest thing.***

> *on one of the views, find the property called ***keepScreenOn*** and set it*
>   ***true.***

That's it. It works like a charm :)

Comment: keepScreenOn is bringing a rocketlauncher to a knife fight if you only want the mediaplayer to keep playing.

Comment: @REJH What is the alternate solution you suggest?
keepScreenOn is suggested way(by the android team) as compared to wakelocks to keep a screen on.

Comment: The question doesn't say he wants to keep the screen on. He wants wifi to stay awake. (See his comment below where he explicitly says so: "Thing is, I'm wanting people listening to the radio with this app to be able to put their phone in standby"). In general it's a bad idea to keep the screen on for music playback. If it were a video stream I'd agree with your solution.

Comment: @REJH Thanks for taking the time to explain this; makes sense. For some reason, I think I didn't pay particular attention to the kind of usage.

Comment: It's a particular case :) There are some more problems with mediaplayer class and online streams the dev has to solve

Answer (score -1):

First you should use the prepareAsync() instead of prepare() because the buffering might take a little while, and with this method the whole work will be done in a separated Thread ...
You can also add some listeners that will surely help organizing your code and methods ;) .